# pandas display results grouped by column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I'm trying to essentially do the same as a pivot table in Excel would do but using pandas. Here is some of my data:

```
  First_Name            Last_Name   Country Prize_Money
       Roger              Federer       SUI    88691538
       Novak             Djokovic       SRB    72444493
      Rafael                Nadal       ESP    71421511
        Andy               Murray       GBR    34190085
       David               Ferrer       ESP    24928109
```

The output would be the Country and the sum of the Prize_Money column:

```
    Country Sum_Prize_Money
    ESP     96349620
    GBR     34190085
```

and so on.

I created a DataFrame object with the data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(Analysis_ATP_data_list, columns=['Ranking',
                                                   'First_Name',
                                                   'Last_Name',
                                                   'Country',
                                                   'Prize_Money'])
```

and wish I could print the grouped_by summary to the screen.

Thank you in advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html):

```
>>> df.groupby("Country")["Prize_Money"].sum()
Country
ESP        96349620
GBR        34190085
SRB        72444493
SUI        88691538
Name: Prize_Money, dtype: int64
```

if you want a Series as output, or maybe

```
>>> df.groupby("Country", as_index=False)["Prize_Money"].sum()
  Country  Prize_Money
0     ESP     96349620
1     GBR     34190085
2     SRB     72444493
3     SUI     88691538
```

if you want a frame.  Reading the docs on [grouping](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#group-by-split-apply-combine) is probably a good idea.

---

More complicated aggregations are possible too:

```
>>> df.groupby("Country", as_index=False).agg({"Prize_Money": ["sum", "count"]})
  Country Prize_Money      
                  sum count
0     ESP    96349620     2
1     GBR    34190085     1
2     SRB    72444493     1
3     SUI    88691538     1
```

Comment: Fantastic! Will read more on groupby. How would you add a Count to the displayed data?

>>> df.groupby("Country")["Prize_Money"].sum()

Comment: I've added an example, but it's a better idea to work through the tutorial yourself.  Otherwise you'll be missing out on all sorts of neat pivots you can do.

Comment: very, very interesting. Thank you! Will definitely work through the tutorial. Thank you for adding the specific example!

Comment: done. Can't upvote as I don't have enough reputation. Will do when I get it! :)